# nt segue identifier not detecting the segue

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to switch views using segues (not my first time) , the segue activity is being recognized however no action happens

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"thesegue" sender: self];
...
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSString *string=[segue identifier]; //checked if the string is actually equal "thesegue" unsing a breakpoint , and it s actually the case


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"thesegue"]) { 

        int x;
        x=2

    }
}
```

I have inserted breakpoints over all lines and it just jumps to the last closing bracket (i.e. it doesn t recognize the [segue identifier] as equal to "thesegue") .

am I missing something ?

EDIT :

I added x=2 and now it goes into the if statment , the question now is , knowing that it detects the segue , why doesn t it show the new view ?

Comment: Did you replace your segue identifier with `thesegue` when you pasted this code? This looks fine, but if you had something other than `thesegue`, I wonder if your original code may have used different capitalization in one or the other, as this is case sensitive.

Comment: since I have only one segue in this file I made it as is . I am aware of the case sensitivity ...
is the fact that it is a modal segue have an effect somehow ?

Comment: No, that wouldn't cause a problem. Another stupid question: Does your `if` statement's block of code have something other than just the `int x`, because if not, the compiler would just jump over it. Did you remove some code inside that `if` block for the sake of clarity, or is this really what your block of code is? But if `[segue identifier]` is really `@"thesegue"`, there's no reason that I could imagine that `isEqualToString:@"thesegue"` would fail.

Comment: Now it comes down to whether you've specified the identifier for the segue in your storyboard correctly. Or is your new scene's view controller class set correctly? Try putting a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` of the new view controller and let's see what happens.

Comment: This is the first thing I did , the segue is correctly put in the storyboard , I have put breakpoints in the 'viewDidLoad' function of the new view controller and it was not detected . I tried to change the segue name several times but nothing happened

Comment: I'd try giving the new scene's view controller an identifier and then manually invoking `MyController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"putyourviewcontroleridentifierhere"]; [self presentViewController:controller];`. That takes the segue out of the loop (temporarily). If it works, then problem is with segue. If it doesn't, then problem is with the new view controller and its view. If you're game, feel free to zip up your project and upload it somewhere and I'm willing to take a look, too.

Comment: I didn t work ...
I lost hope and changed the logic and it s working now 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try performSegue in `ViewDidAppear` method !!

Answer (score -1):

The segue identifier is set in the storyboard/IB.  Set it to that and make your connections properly and it will work.

Comment: He already mentioned `[segue identifier]` is equals to that string,.

Comment: yes the segue Identifier works , I edited my question to add more precision , the problem is that even though the segue is detected , the new view does not show ...